# extension protocol which about UIViewController how to use the UIViewcontroller's property

Tags: ios, swift

```
public protocol NavigationBarNormalStyle {
    var titleView: UIToolbar! {get}
    var rightButton: UIButton? {get}
}

public extension NavigationBarNormalStyle where Self == UIViewController {

    var titleView:UIToolbar {
        var titleViewBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:Self.view.width, height: 44))
        titleViewBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        Self.view.addSubview(titleViewBar)
    }

}
```

`Self.view.width` is wrong... How to use the vc's property?

Answer (score 0):

You want to access instance properties, but `Self` is the *class* of your object, not the object itself.

Your should write `self.view`, etc.